# Using checkboxGroupInput choices with NA

Tags: r, shiny

I can't figure out how to use NA within a checkboxGroupInput.  In the example below, I want to be able to select all NA values and all "M" values for instance.  But I'm unable to select the NA values.

The filtering works for the dataframe outside of the Shiny app, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with input$b_select.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

a = 1:10
b = c('M', 'F', NA, NA, NA, 'F', NA, 'M', 'F', NA)

test_data <- tibble(a, b)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$total <- renderText({  

    data <- test_data %>%
      filter(b %in% input$b_select)

    paste("Total:", nrow(data), sep = ' ')   
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

      checkboxGroupInput("b_select", 
                         label = "B:", 
                         choices = c('M', 'F', NA),
                         selected = c('M', 'F', NA)
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("total"))
  )
))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting `NA` in `checkboxGroupInput` actually returns empty string `""`.

You can use with `is.na` to fix the filter:

```
data <- test_data %>%
  filter( b %in% input$b_select | ( is.na(b) & "" %in% input$b_select ) )
```